# Power app canvas app with snowflake as backend

Tags: sharepoint, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerapps, power-platform

Need your suggestions in one scenario.

I have developed an canvas app using SharePoint as data source. Now client wants same app to be developed using snowflake as datasource. Is it possible I know there is connector available but functions which works for SharePoint will not work right for snowflake. Can you give some inputs on this

There is an issue in executing functions which work fluently in SP than in snowflake.